# Is it possible to install both Gstreamer 0.10 and Gstreamer 1.0 at the same time?

Tags: debian, java, shared-library, gstreamer

I have a computer that runs Debian Stretch which has Gstreamer 1.0 installed. I am trying to run a Processing sketch that uses the Processing video library which in turn relies on Gstreamer 0.10. This produces a runtime error because they removed a symbol `gst_object_sink`.

It seems a PITA to try to rebuild the Processing video library with different Java bindings for Gstreamer 1.0.

Thus the question: **Is it possible to install on the same system a second version (0.10) of Gstreamer**?

---

The problem seems to be that [libgstreamer0.10-0](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libgstreamer0.10-0) appears in Wheezy, Jessie, SID, but not Stretch/Testing.... Why would that be, and how to fix it?

Comment: Debian is switching to GStreamer 1.0 and has therefore already GStreamer 0.10 removed from Debian Stretch/Testing. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=802812 . It will also be removed from Sid/Unstable as soon as all programs are update to the new GStreamer release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perfectly possible to install multiple versions of a library in Debian. **Pinning** is the way to go. In this case I decided to obtain `libgstreamer0.10` from Debian Unstable (running Debian Testing myself).

Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/unstable.list` with contents:

```
deb http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
deb-src http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/ unstable main
```

Then, create `/etc/apt/preferences.d/unstable` with contents:

```
Package: *
Pin: release a=unstable
Pin-Priority: 200
```

Now run `apt-get update`. To check if everything went ok, type `apt-cache policy libgstreamer0.10-0`. It should report something like:

```
libgstreamer0.10-0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.10.36-1.5
  Version table:
     0.10.36-1.5 50
        200 http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Note that this adds all packages from unstable with a lower priority. It is also possible to single out one or a few packages. See the [documentation on pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) for more details.

PS For me the reason to do this was solving an RStudio dependency on `libgstreamer-0.10`: "rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: libgstreamer-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" (added these details so others may find this after a search).

PPS The link given by @jofel (partly) answers the why part of your question.

Comment: Thanks. So if `200` is a lower priority, what is the "default" priority of my stable system?

Comment: That would be 500. You can check with any installed package, e.g. `apt-cache policy tasksel`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get processing-video 2.2.1 to work, installing the corresponding Debian Jessie .deb files downloaded via https://pkgs.org:

- gstreamer-0.10-gconf
- gstreamer-0.10-plugins-base
- libgstreamer0.10-0
- libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0

Installing each via `dpkg -i`. Others such as 'plugins-good' have unsatisfied dependencies, but were not needed in my case.